# POSTMAN-NEWMAN: 403 Forbidden error message

Tags: api, jenkins, postman, http-status-code-403, newman

1) Newman Version (can be found via newman -v): `version is 4.6`

2) OS details (type, version, and architecture): `RHEL 7.4`

3) Are you using Newman as a library, or via the CLI? Downloaded Newman via npm

4) Did you encounter this recently, or has this bug always been there: We are executing our postman collections through newman in Jenkins for the first time.

5) Expected behaviour: `status 200`

6) Command / script used to run Newman: `HTTP_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx HTTPS_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx newman run collections.json --reporters junit,html,xml`

We are trying to automate the execution of API test collections using Newman in Jenkins. The collections are executing properly in postman, but we are getting 403 forbidden when we execute them in Jenkins. We are getting outputs like these:

```
GET http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/api/add-lead/ [403 Forbidden, 2.69KB, 133ms]

There was an error running your collection: tunneling socket couldn't be established, statusCode=403
```

We have installed Jenkins and necessary capabilities to execute postman collections in a Jenkins agent. Jenkins, agent, the IPs mentioned in GET, PUT commands are in our bank's internal network.

What could be the reason because we have scanned through similar issues, but found no satisfactory answers.

Please tell me if you need any other details.

Regards

Comment: I know this is late for the OP, but maybe for future readers it could be helpful. I have had the same problem. The reason was that the server was configured to always need a client certificate, which was properly sent from Postman, but not from newman. You can pass the certificate, private key and the password using these options: `--ssl-client-cert <path> --ssl-client-key <path> --ssl-client-passphrase <password>`.

Comment: I'm adding this for people moving to Newman because Postman is limiting the number of collections that can be run per month. When exporting the collection variables, only those in the 'Initial value' column are exported.